# How to avoid Klockwork warning on initialization and assignment in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, klocwork

I am running static code analysis and found warnings.

For the below code snippet I get warnings as specified in the code. Is there a workaround to implement following code to resolve warnings?

```
int foo(bool cond)
{
    int var = 0; // Value of "var" never used after initial
    if(cond){
       var = 10; // Value of "var" never used after assignment
    }
    else{
       var = 20; // Value of "var" never used after assignment
    }
    return var;
}

void main(){
    cout << foo(true);
    return;
}
```

Comment: you cannot return an `int` from a `void` function. Please show the real code

Comment: btw I cannot access any of your links.

Comment: Warnings are mentioned in the code snippet

Comment: please show the actual code that produces the warnings ([mcve]). `if(/*some_condition*/) var = 10;` is an error, not a warning

Comment: If the static analysis is certain you never use the return value of this function, then it's correct that these values are never used, right? So check whether it shows you where this is called from when it generates the warning. You might consider using the [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute if you have C++17, to help track it down.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do is to remove the initial dead assignment:

```
int foo(bool cond)
{
    int var; // Declare, but don't initialise
    if (cond) {
       var = 10;
    } else {
       var = 20;
    }
    return var;
}
```

Or (better), eliminate the variable entirely:

```
int foo(bool cond)
{
    return cond ? 10 : 20;
}
```